# Permission denied error when trying to SSH through a script

Tags: bash, ssh, permissions, ssh-tunnel

I have a set of Bash scripts designed to establish an SSH connection from a local machine to a remote server through a middle server. The local script initiates a tunnel using socat, and the middle server script spawns the tunnel, but when attempting to SSH into the final destination, I encounter a "Permission denied" error. It seems like the password is incorrect but is not true and it also seems that it gives this error due to trying to login on the middleserver and not on the target with the credentials.

local-script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SERIAL="$1"
USER="$2"
PASSWORD="$3"

function launch_socat(){
    serial="$1"
    ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[middleserver]:7778" &> /dev/null
    ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[middleservername]:7778" &> /dev/null
    tmux kill-session -t opentunnel >& /dev/null
    tmux new -d -s opentunnel
    tmux send-keys -t opentunnel 'ssh defaultuser@middleserver' C-m
    tmux send-keys -t opentunnel "sleep 2 && /home/defaultuser/middle-script.sh $serial" C-m
    sleep 10
}

launch_socat "$SERIAL"

sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$USER"@middleserver -p 7778
```

middle-script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

p1=7779
p2=7778
ser=$1
server_addr=middleip

nohup socat TCP4-LISTEN:$p1,reuseaddr TCP4-LISTEN:$p2,reuseaddr &

sleep 1

mosquitto_pub -h mymqtt -p mqttport -t "mymqttcommand/$ser/0/command/run_script" -u 'mymqttuser' -P 'mymqttpassword' -m "ssh_tunnel_spawn $server_addr $p1"  -d --cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I've opened the necessary ports in the sshd configuration on the middle server and set up password authentication, but the issue persists.

Attempts Made:

Verified the correctness of the provided password. Checked the existence and permissions of the remote user on the destination server. Reviewed SSH server logs for detailed error information but it didn't help.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
Client ssh verbose logs

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/myuser/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to middleip [middleip] port 7778.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to middleip:7778 as 'attempteduser'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:OLuDWVmWtP16hBFSL8mX9Y08lFy8iPwmYtJX0wwSRzw
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
Warning: Permanently added '[middleip]:7778' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa rsa sha256
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa rsa sha256
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
Permission denied, please try again.
```

middle server logs

```
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: Connection from myip port 31093 on middleip port 7778 rdomain ""
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 112/65534 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: resetting send seqnr 3 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: resetting read seqnr 3 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: userauth-request for user attempteduser service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: Invalid user attempteduser from myip port 31093
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "attempteduser"
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "myip"
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: userauth-request for user attempteduser service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob rsa sha256 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: userauth-request for user attempteduser service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=myip 
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Go
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: no match: Go
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 112/65534 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:14 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:15 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "anotherip"
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650085]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for an illegal user: Authentication failure
Jan 17 08:15:16 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: Failed password for invalid user attempteduser from myip port 31093 ssh2
Jan 17 08:15:17 my-middle-server sshd[1650086]: Connection closed by invalid user attempteduser myip port 31093 [preauth]
```

Comment: We are going to need verbose client and server logs to diagnose this problem.

Comment: edited with logs @Ramhound

Comment: Side note: `tmux new-window` can pass shell code directly to your default shell, e.g. try `tmux new-window 'date; uname -a; sleep 3'`. Similarly `ssh` can pass shell code to a remote shell, try `ssh user@server 'date; uname -a'`. Prefer these over `tmux send-keys`. Sending keystrokes is a poor way to execute code.

Comment: Your server is rejecting any attempt to access *attempteduser* because it doesn’t exist. Make sure the user you are trying to attempt actually exists on all servers and clients

Comment: The user exists on the target. If i create it also on the middle server then the scripts end in logging me into the middle @Ramhound

Comment: @FLSill - Your server logs clearly indicated the user does not exist. “password authentication failed for an illegal user: Authentication failure” so you are either trying to authenticate as root or the user doesn’t exist specifically “Invalid user attempteduser from myip port 31093”

Comment: Make sure the user has a shell defined. You can do this by authenticating as a user that does work, “su - attempteduser” or use root to define which shell should be used